# Touching points are dense (viscosity theory)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, viscosity-solutions

I am on a course about viscosity theory and we had this as an exercise:

Assume $u: \Omega \to R$ is bounded and upper semicontinuous. Fix $x_0$. Prove that for every $r>0$ there is $\phi\in C^2(B(x_0,r))$ such that for some $y\in B(x_0,r)$ $\phi(y)=u(y)$ and $\phi(x)\geq u(x)$ for every $x\in B(x_0,r)-\{y\}$.

The hint was to choose $\phi(x)=a+b|x-x_0|^2$ and I know that I need to fix $a$ to be such that $\phi(y)=u(y)$ and b such that $\phi(x)\geq u(x)$, but I don't know how.

Comment: See the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067940/viscosity-solution-for-hamilton-jacobi-equations-and-local-extrema/3071678#3071678

Comment: @Jeff 
But I don't see why in my case u attains its maximum on $B(x_0,r)$? And I don't understand why that would guarantee an existence of a test function on that maximum point.

Comment: An upper semi-continuous function attains its max over a compact set. The test function is the thing subtracted from u.

Comment: @Jeff   So it doesn't matter if I take the closed ball instead of the open ball? Density requires a neighborhood, so I think it should be an open ball

Comment: Take the closed ball to ensure the max exists. Then since the sequence of maximum points $x_\varepsilon$ converges to $x_0$ (the center of the ball) as $\varepsilon\to 0$, the max is eventually over the open ball for $\varepsilon$ small enough. The entire proof is in the posting linked above; it is exactly your setting.

Comment: @Jeff   Now I see, thanks for your answer!